# Azure functions Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

As I understand, so long as I setup grants to KeyVault, my function should be able to read from it by using

`@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=MYSECRETFULLURL)`, and I assume this would be transformed at run-time?

Any idea how I would debug this?

Currently, as thats getting to my function, is the above, with nothing transformed.

Running as system-managed.

If I debug, this is all I get:

[image]

However I *can* see my audit on azure key vault its being hit.
[image]

```
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var accountToMoveFrom = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("accountToMonitor");
            log.LogCritical(accountToMoveFrom);
            var accessToken = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("accessToken");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the final resolution:

Make sure you **do not** have the "authorized application" or applicationId settings configured.

[From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references)

Create an access policy in Key Vault for the application identity you created earlier. Enable the "Get" secret permission on this policy. **Do not configure the "authorized application" or applicationId settings, as this is not compatible with a managed identity.**

> Note: Does your code actually work? Logging the value of a key is intercepted and is displayed as
>
> ```
> @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=MYSECRETFULLURL)
> ```
>
> in logs to avoid sensitive configuration from KeyVault ending up in
> log files that may reach a wider audience.

It works fine [as per the docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simplifying-security-for-serverless-and-web-apps-with-azure-functions-and-app-service/) (extract below), also double check you have:

- Managed Service Identity (MSI) configured on the function app
- Restarted your function app after adding the function's app setting
- The function's MSI is given access to to the relevant KeyVault, not to the Management Plane but on the Access Policies.

[image]

- If you are running/debugging locally in Visual Studio, you need to give the account signed in to Visual Studio rights on the Key  Vault since because it is the identity presented.

> **Sourcing Application Settings from Key Vault** The Key Vault references feature makes it so that your app can work as if it were
> using App Settings as they have been, meaning no code changes are
> required. You can get all of the details from our Key Vault reference
> documentation, but I’ll outline the basics here.
>
> This feature requires a system-assigned managed identity for your app.
> Later in this post I’ll be talking about user-assigned identities, but
> we’re keeping these previews separate for now.
>
> You’ll then need to configure an access policy on your Key Vault which
> gives your application the GET permission for secrets. Learn how to
> configure an access policy.
>
> Lastly, set the value of any application setting to a reference of the
> following format:
>
> @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=secret_uri_with_version)
>
> Where secret_uri_with_version is the full URI for a secret in Key
> Vault. For example, this would be something like:
> https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931

[image]

Comment: The code works .. but the settings aren't getting thru... Thanks for the pointers RE logging! I'll try again tomorrow!

Comment: How are you setting / passing accountId - seems like you have the key name and not the value.

Comment: I'm getting it via `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("accountId");` and that's set in `ApplicationSettings` in the function (at Azure), which in turn then should point to azure key vault - the application setting is: https://my-key-store.vault.azure.net/secrets/AccountId/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931

Comment: That looks right. Have you tried recreating a simple function app and testing there? Also, grab the whole collection (GetEnvironmentVariables as opposed to GetEnvironmentVariable) and enumerate the collection to see if it is just the one variable or many. Also, is it function 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I'll try that. It's 2.0

Comment: Ok - Made a new project, new KeyVault - no dice - I've added my project into Github to showcase exactly how I'm doing it - not all resources are throw away

https://github.com/stusklinar/kvtest/tree/master/TestFunction

Comment: Tried your code and it works 100% fine. One thing to check, make sure you 
 restart your function app after adding the function's app setting. You can do this through the portal using the Stop and Play/Start buttons. Otherwise it is somewhere in your config.

Comment: I've restarted a few times and every time I think

Comment: This is the URL https://testfunction20190307014206.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?code=mIZgxD4zpLQCulONnqfovQxbqQEaNTHd71Mi6DxW8PawfzqsHLEorA==

Comment: And have you run it from the test pane from within Azure functions? It may be worthwhile logging out the user identity in the code and making sure that user has access to the key vault and the secret store under ACCESS POLICIES.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189684/discussion-between-stuart-sklinar-and-murray-foxcroft).

Comment: @AndrewSumner I have added the root cause to the top of my answer.  Stuart please accept it as the answer.